# Python: requests.exceptions.SSLError

Tags: python, ssl

I am trying to create a page using below python script

```
from atlassian import Confluence

confluence = Confluence(
    url='https://my.domain.com',
    username='admin',
    password='admin')

status = confluence.create_page(
    space='DEMO',
    title='This is the title',
    body='This is the body. You can use <strong>HTML tags</strong>!')


print(status)
```

While running above script facing error as

`requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my.domain.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/api/content (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:618)'),))`

Comment: I've been having a lot of trouble with requests (which seems to be used by Confluence, regarding to you Exception). I'm now mostly using requests with the "verify=True" argument... But maybe you can't force this directly in the confluence module

Answer (score -1):

After peeking at the [github code](https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api), maybe you can use

```
Confluence(
    url='https://my.domain.com',
    username='admin',
    password='admin',
    verify_ssl=False
)
```

But event if this works, it is not resolving the problem with the SSL connexion...

Comment: Even i have gone through https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api/blob/e3a70b7e136140c87c633 90c295ab99c0b1ae3aa/atlassian/rest_client.py#L27, but it's not working.  Facing ```    verify_ssl=False
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If am using crowd user management, how can i get token and pass here ?

Comment: Strange... There is a kwargs in the Confluence class's __init__ method, which inherits the AtlassianRestApi (which has a verify_ssl argument). Did you check if your module has the same code ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with the crowd api, I haven't been using these modules (though I have been using requests a lot and it reminded me of my troubles with the SSL...) - btw, can you post which version of atlassian you are using ?